# Filter operations on WebApi HelpPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2019

I have an action call "Authenticate" and in the WebApiConfig I added a Map for call this action.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "LoginApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/login",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Authenticate" }
);
```

Now in the HelpPage I got two operations for the same action, and I only want one.

`POST api/Login/Authenticate`

`POST api/Login`

How can I filter/hide the operations in HelpPage and only show one?
Like:

`POST api/Login`

I can not use `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` because it is going to hide the two actions.

This is the package that I am using:
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage 5.2.7

Comment: In swagger there is something call ```c.DocumentFilter<ApplyDocumentVendorExtensions>();```, but i am no using swagger.

Comment: You can build your own custom attribute and use IDocumentFilter. 
Here is a solution: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/153

Comment: I am using HelpPage, that solution works for swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `ApiGroup.cshtml`:
[image]

There is a `foreach` that you can hide the operations that you want, like this:

```
@foreach (var api in Model)
{
    string[] paths = new string[] { "api/Login/authenticate" };
    if(paths.Contains(api.RelativePath))
    { continue; }

    <tr>
        <td class="api-name">
           <a href="@Url.Action("Api", "Help", 
              new { apiId = api.GetFriendlyId() })">
              @api.HttpMethod.Method @api.RelativePath
           </a></td>
        <td class="api-documentation">
        @if (api.Documentation != null)
        {
            <p>@api.Documentation</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No documentation available.</p>
        }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In this block I added this code:

```
string[] paths = new string[] { "api/Login/authenticate" };
if(paths.Contains(api.RelativePath))
{ 
   continue; 
}
```

With this, you can check what you want to show.

Comment: With this, I solve my problem but I would like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special route. `DefaultApi` will [route your action by convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api). Remove you custom `LoginApi` route and use convention method in your controller

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    public void Post()
    {
        // authenticate here
    }
}
```

or if you insist on naming the action `Authenticate`, you can use routing variation by HTTP verb

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Authenticate()
    {
        // authenticate here
    }
}
```

That will make API explorer generate the help page you want:
[image: ASP.NET Web Api Help Page]

### Edit

To support multiple action methods that share the same HTTP verb you should configure routing by action name similarly like you did, but I don't see `{action}` parameter in your route. It should be:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "LoginApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/Login/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Authenticate" }
);
```

By specifying the default action like above, the URL `/api/Login` will be correctly routed to `LoginController.Authenticate`, however the action will show up as `POST api/Login/Authenticate` on help page, because `ApiExplorer` somehow doesn't recognize the default action. To fix that I would rather stay away from hacking help page like you did in your own answer, because it can bite you back. You could instead force the route for your default action using the [`RouteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn433929(v%3Dvs.118)). The controller code would then lokk like this:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Login")]
    public void Authenticate()
    {
        // authenticate here
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Register()
    {
        // register here
    }
}
```

The help page would then display:

> POST api/Login
>
> POST api/Login/Register

Comment: I can not use this approach because I do not get the actions by HTTP verbs, I get the actions by name.
In the same "Login" controller I have "Register" action and so on.

Comment: @RabelObispo I have updated my answer according to your comment. Next time make sure to include all relevant information in your question.